# What is was the total corporate Income earned in the United States in 2014?

Tags: data-request, taxation

> What is was the total corporate income earned in the United States in 2014?

The question may seem simple, but I have been looking for a reliable source to inform me of this figure, and I hope someone out there can help me find a reliable figure and source.

Comment: Only "C corporations"   (as distinguished from an "S corporations")?

Answer (score 1):

Not for 2014 but here is a useful 2012 report using 2007 data: *[Taxing Businesses Through the Individual Income Tax](https://www.cbo.gov/publication/43750)* (CBO (2012))
[image]

It shows how taxed corporations like S corps have been in long run decline (in share terms) relative to pass through entities. Which makes it tricky because, increasingly, corporate income isn't taxable at the corporate entity and so  taxes paid on total corporate income might be a poor measure of the taxes on corporate profits because so much is taxed on individual tax returns.

The BEA, as part of the NIPA publishes a number of corporate profit measures. [You can see many of them on FRED](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/categories/33033). You may be particularly interested in *Gross domestic income: Corporate profits with inventory valuation and capital consumption adjustments, domestic industries: Profits after tax with inventory valuation and capital consumption adjustments*:
[image]